# Working with several view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am developing a very simple Swift application programmatically (without storyboards). I have a HomeViewController

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createButton(){

        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(100,200,50,50)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "timerPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }

}
```

And I have the following

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let home = HomeViewController()
        home.createButton()
    }

}
```

When I call home.createButton() i expect a button to display, but currently it does not. I know the method works because when I moved that createButton() method into the ViewController class it displays the button. Am I missing something with how to properly call the createButton method from within the HomeViewController. Is there a better convention to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of homeviewcontroller it's view doesn't exist in the view hierarchy

Comment: you are not adding your button to a vie controller you are calling

Comment: You should add homeViewController as a child controller of viewController. Something like `addChildViewController(home) self.view.addSubview(home.view)`

Comment: One problem I see here is that you may be creating your HomeViewController but you are not showing it. Also, you are creating `home` in function scope, so when that function ends, so does the reference to the HomeViewController object you created.

Comment: Can I assume that ViewController is your initial view controller?

Answer (score 1):

```
    class func createButton(controller: UIViewcontroller){

            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.frame = CGRectMake(100,200,50,50)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "timerPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            controller.view.addSubview(button)

        }
```

Now call this method to any ViewController

Like This :

> HomeViewController.createButton(self).

Answer (score 0):

You can write **createButton** code under *loadview()* method of your HomeViewController

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

  override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(100,200,50,50)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "timerPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

so there is no need to call extra method of **HomeViewController** to add button as a subview of it.